# How to join three table

Tags: mysql

I'm having three tables, two of which are same in structure

**table1 like this**

```
-----------------------------------------------
id       title     description       image
-----------------------------------------------
1         title1   desc1             image1.png
2         title2    desc2            image2.jpg
------------------------------------------------
```

**table2 like this**

```
-----------------------------------------------
id       title     description       image
-----------------------------------------------
1         ttl1   des1             img1.png
2         ttl2    des2            img2.jpg
------------------------------------------------
```

**table 3 like this**

```
-----------------------------------------------
id       table1_id    table2_id     
-----------------------------------------------
1         0             1             
2         1             0    
------------------------------------------------
```

I want to join table3 to one of the other tables where id is not zero.

Comment: Please show us the SQL expression you tried. We're happy to help, but we won't do all your work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table3  t3 
join table1 t1 on t1.id = t3.table2_id     
join table2 t2 on t2.id = t3.table1_id    
Where t3.table2_id <> 0 or  t3.table1_id    <> 0
```

Use direct [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) with `Where`

Answer (score 0):

```
(select * from table3 as t3 join table1 as t1 on t1.id = t3.id and t3.table1_id != 0)
UNION
(select * from table3 as t3 join table2 as t2 on t2.id = t3.id and t3.table2_id != 0)
```